# Error with Android Studio while using Tyrus websockets

Tags: android, android-studio, websocket, tyrus

Im making an android application with websockets using the latest Tyrus build using android studio. I have included the library through gradle like so on build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles:tyrus-standalone-client:1.10'
}
```

with android targetting versions

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 21
```

Every time I run the compile button i get the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/dorian/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/dorian/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/glassfish/tyrus/client/ClientManager$1$1;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

My application is based on the following sample

https://github.com/pavelbucek/tyrus-client-android-test

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any version of tyrus jar in `lib` directory?

Comment: I feel such and idiot. Well this what you get when you venture in a new territory. Thanks a bunch Ondrej, I completely forgot that I manually put the libs directory some time ago.
Seems to be working properly now.